# Karma error: Failed: this.alertController.getAlerts is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a angular project that i want to write unit test for. Whenever the test gets to the getAlert function in the code i get this error : Failed: this.alertController.getAlerts is not a function. I have no idea what to do here.

alert.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AlertController} from '../../controllers/AlertController';
import {Alert} from '../../entities/Alert';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert',
  templateUrl: './alert.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alert.component.css']
})
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {

  alerts: Alert[];

  constructor(private alertController: AlertController) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.alertController.getAlerts().subscribe(alert => {
      this.alerts = alert;
    });
  }
}
```

alert.component.spec.ts

```
import {async, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {AlertComponent} from './alert.component';
import {of} from 'rxjs';
import {AlertController} from '../../controllers/AlertController';


const alertServiceStub = {
  get() {
    const alert = [
      {
        alertId: 1,
        alertMessage: 'test message',
        transactionContext: null,
        state: null
      }];
    return of( alert );
  }
};

describe('RuleOverViewComponentTest', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AlertComponent
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [AlertComponent, {provide: AlertController, useValue: alertServiceStub}],
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the component', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AlertComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should create the component', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AlertComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(document.querySelectorAll('#alert').length).toEqual(1);
  }));
});
```

AlertController.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlertController {

  alertUrl: string;

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.alertUrl = 'http://localhost:8091/alert-service/';
  }

  public getAlerts(): Observable<Alert[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Alert[]>(this.alertUrl + 'alert');
  }

  public getAlert(alertId: number): Observable<Alert> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Alert>(this.alertUrl + 'alert/' + alertId);
  }

  public blockCard(alertId: number) {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.alertUrl + 'blockCard/', alertId);
  }

  public closeAlert(alertId: number) {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.alertUrl + 'closeAlert', alertId);
  }
}
```

I'm getting this with every function in every test i try to make. But as far as i know the way i made the functions is perfectly fine. so whats really going on, how can i make the test succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `alertServiceStub` is missing the getAlert() method try adding it in like below:

```
const alertServiceStub = {
  getAlert() {
    const alert = [
      {
        alertId: 1,
        alertMessage: 'test message',
        transactionContext: null,
        state: null
      }];
    return of( alert );
  }
};
```

Since this is the value your unit test will actually use for testing, you'll want to make sure any methods you call exist in this mock object.